# Swift NSUserDefaults not saving Dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have the following test code:

```
  func testSaveDictionary() {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var jo = [
      "a" : "1.0",
      "b" : "2.0"
    ]

    let akey = "aKey"
    userDefaults.setObject(jo, forKey: akey)
    var isOk = userDefaults.synchronize()

    var data0 = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey(akey)
    println(data0)

  }
```

The output of println(data0) is nil.

Anything wrong with my code? Is Swift Dictionary considered property list now or in the final release?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Update for **Swift 2, Xcode 7:** As @atxe noticed, NSUserDefaults dictionaries are now mapped as `[String, AnyObject]`. This is a 
consequence of the Objective-C "lightweight generics" which allow
to declare the Objective-C method as

```
- (NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)dictionaryForKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

(Default objects must be property lists and in particular the dictionary
keys can only be strings.)

On the other hand, a Swift dictionary is bridged automatically if possible, so the original code from the question works (again):

```
let jo = [
    "a" : "1.0",
    "b" : "2.0"
]

let akey = "aKey"
// Swift 2:
userDefaults.setObject(jo, forKey: akey)
// Swift 3:
userDefaults.set(jo, forKey: akey)
```

---

Original answer for **Swift 1.2:** 
The user defaults can store `NSDictionary` objects. These are mapped to Swift
as `[NSObject : AnyObject]`:

```
var jo : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
    "a" : "1.0",
    "b" : "2.0"
] 
userDefaults.setObject(jo, forKey: akey)
var isOk = userDefaults.synchronize()
```

And note that `dictionaryForKey()` returns an optional, so you should check it
for example with an optional assignment:

```
if let data0 = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey(akey) {
    print(data0)
} else {
    print("not set")
}

// Output: [b: 2.0, a: 1.0]
```

Comment: right on! the key is to explicitly declare: var jo : [NSObject : AnyObject] as you mentioned above.

Comment: Another way around (in case for some reason you can't make the declaration explicit) would be to use "as NSDictionary": userDefaults.setObject((jo as NSDictionary), forKey: aKey)

Comment: In Swift 2.0 NSUserDefault dictionaries are mapped as [String : AnyObject]. Actually if you try to save a Dictionary with Int (for instance) as key, it fails in runtime. You can define your extension with a strong typed method to safely support and avoid a possible runtime error, although it would be nice to have such trivial method provided by Apple.

Comment: I would suggest editing the answer, so that the Swift 2.0 version was on top.

Comment: "in particular the dictionary keys can only be strings" got rid of my `UserDefaults` crash. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You need to convert it into `NSData` first. Something like this:

```
var data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(jo)
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(data, forKey:akey)
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced with this problem yesterday and filed a radar: [Cannot store Dictionary in NSUserDefaults in iOS8](http://openradar.appspot.com/18403298). This issue is related only to iOS 8.  Also I described a workaround for this case: [Workaround for saving dictionary in NSUserDefaults](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508235322/http://szulctomasz.com/workaround-for-saving-dictionary-in-nsuserdefaults/). Works like a charm.

```
/// Save
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(object), forKey: key)

/// Read
var data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as NSData
var object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as [String: String]
```

Comment: Link to "Workaround for saving dictionary in NSUserDefaults" is broken

Answer (score 3):

**Follow this beautiful code below** -> Swift 3

```
public func setDict(dict: NSDictionary) {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict)
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.set(data, forKey:"keyHere")
}


public func getDict() -> NSDictionary {
    let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "keyHere") as! NSData
    let object = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as! NSDictionary
    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**//swift 4.0**

//for saving

```
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    userDefaults.setValue(value, forKey: "Your_Key")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

//for for retrieve

```
        let loadedCart = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "Your_Key")
```

Comment: According to my understanding there are very few reasons for calling `userDefaults.synchronize()`.