# swift - NSUserDefaults fetch list of saved notes

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am developing a Note app. I have developed  a save button that when is pressed it saves the note with a custom name into NSUserDefaults.

I can fetch the contents of the notes however, I cannot figure out how to get a list of the notes saved names.

For examples if a user saved 3 notes custom named like: dogs, cats, food how can I fetch this saved named into a `UITableview`?

To save the notes I use:

```
var noteToSave: NSString = noteResult.text;
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(noteToSave, forKey: nameSave.text)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

to fetch all keys:

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var defaultAsDic: [NSObject : AnyObject] = defaults.dictionaryRepresentation()
        var keyArr: [AnyObject] = defaultAsDic.allKeys()
        for key: String in keyArr {
            NSLog("key [%@] => Value [%@]", key, defaultAsDic.valueForKey(key))
```

but its not working

Comment: Not sure what are you asking.

Comment: I want to show the Keys of the notes saved into a UITableview - I have tried with println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.array) however the app crashes

Comment: Unclear what this is asking. Is the question how to you populate table views? Or how do you fetch things saved in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: You have save your note names somewhere first after that you can read it.

Comment: lets say how to fetch all the keys saved in NSUserDefaults

Comment: `NSTableView`? If you are asking for someone to provide code this is the wrong place, SO is about helping developers with their code, add the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the fetching code.. see my edit

Comment: FYI - `NSUserDefaults` is not the proper place to store your data. Write to a file or a database or something more appropriate than `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

To get noteResult.text you should add this code:

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("\(identity.text!)")
```

Comment: I can get the noteResult.text content. What I need is to get all keys

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example for you:

```
var jo = [
        "a" : "1.0",
        "b" : "2.0"
    ]
//Store your Dictionary into userDefaults.  
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setObject(jo, forKey: "yourKey")

//Get keys from dictionary
var allKeys = [String]()
if let data0 = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey("yourKey") {
    for (key, value) in data0 {
        println("\(key) -> \(value)")
        allKeys.append(key as! String)
    }
} else {
    println("not set")
}

println(allKeys) //[b, a]
```

Now you can display this array into your `tableView`.

Here is original answer: [Swift NSUserDefaults not saving Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752433/swift-nsuserdefaults-not-saving-dictionary)

And saving notes into `NSUserDefaults` is not a good way to store your data.Instead of that you can use other tools like plist, SQLite, etc.

Comment: You should add a link instead of copying the code. Here is the original [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752433/swift-nsuserdefaults-not-saving-dictionary)

Comment: I have added link of original answer as you said..:)